# Proof verification in a functional analysis problem

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, banach-spaces

I am new to Functional Analysis .Please review the following proof:

> Let $X$ be a Banach space. Let $T:X\to X$ be a invertible linear operator and $M>0$ be such that $\|T^{-k}\|<M$ for all $k\ge 1$.
>
> > Prove that $\inf _{n\ge 1} \|T^n(x)\|>0$  for all $x\neq 0$ in $X$

**My try**:

In order to show that $\inf _{n\ge 1} \|T^n(x)\|>0$  for all $x\neq 0$ in $X$
;let us fix $x(\neq 0)\in X$ and then we have to show that $\|T^n(x)\|>0$ for all $n\ge 1$.

Without loss of generality let $\|x\|=1$

Again $T$ is invertible so there exists some $T_1$ such that $TT_1=T_1T=I$.

Since $\|T^{-k}\|<M\implies \sup _{\|x\|=1,x\in X}\|T^{-k}(x)\|
<M\implies \sup {\|(T^k)^{-1}(x)\|}<M$
$\implies \|T^{-k}(x)\|<M$  for all $x$  with $\|x\|=1$

Now for any linear operator $P$; $P^{-1}$ is defined as $P^{-1}(y)=x$ where $P(x)=y$

Then we have $T^{-k}(x)=y$ where $T^k(y)=x$

Now $\|T^{-k}(x)\|<M$  for all $x$  with $\|x\|=1\implies \|y\|<M$ whenever $\|T^k(y)\|=1$ for all $k\ge 1$

Thus 
$\inf _{n\ge 1} \|T^n(x)\|>0$  for all $x\neq 0$.I think that there will be some problems as I have not used the fact that $X$ is Banach.

**Please check this proof and suggest edits if required**. Looking forward to you all.

Comment: To go from $|a_n|<A$ to Sup$|a_n|<A$ and not Sup$|a_n|\le A$ deserves an explanation. (for $a_n=1-\frac 1n$ the Sup is equal to $1$).

Comment: An easier proof would be that if$ \|x_n\|=1$ and $\|T^nx_n\|<1/n$ for infinitely many $n\in N,$ then $1=\|x\|=\|T^{-n}T^nx_n\|\leq M\|T^nx_n\|<M/n$ for infinitely many $n\in N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption there exists $M>0$ such that for all $y\in X$, $n\ge 1$:

$$ \|T^{-n} (y)\|\le M\|y\|.$$

Let $x$ be given. Set  $y=T^n x$. To obtain

$$ \|x\| = \|T^{-n} (T^n x) \| \le M \|T^n x\| .$$

Therefore

$$\inf_{n} \|T^n x\| \ge \frac{\|x\|}{M}.$$